# Unable to install rpm package in Red Hat Linux

Tags: redhat, rpm

I am using Red Hat Linux installed on VMWare ESXi.

I am using putty to access the machine.

I want to install `xyz.noarch.rpm` package on RHEL system.
When I try the command

`rpm -ivh xyz.noarch.rpm`

I get an error `package already installed`.

When I verify the same by using the `rpm -q xyz.noarch.rpm`.

I get response as `package xyz.noarch.rpm is not installed`.
I also tried with the uninstalling the same by using the command as `rpm -ev xyz.noarch.rpm` the also I get the same response as `package xyz.noarch.rpm is not installed`.

Can anybody help me to sort out the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is named `xyz.noarch.rpm`, but in the database it's just `xyz`. So try `rpm -qi xyz`.

Answer (score 0):

i faced a similar issue and found that both installation and removal (erase) was not working for a rpm package that i installed. i tried using

```
rpm -e --allmatches <package-name>
```

more info at : http://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2002-March/msg00138.html